# Changing theme in Pyscripter?

Tags: python, pyscripter

I have installed it using the executable file downloaded from its webpage. 
I tried finding %AppData%\skins\ as suggested by blogs but I just couldn't find it. Has anybody been stuck here?

Answer (score 2):

For me (using Win7/Pyscripter 2.5.0.3 x86) the correct location for these is `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Pyscripter\skins`

Ensure you have put the '.skn' file there and not the downloaded executable or archive file (.zip, etc)

Once you start or restart Pyscripter the theme will be available under View menu > Themes.

Additional: If you have installed a very different coloured theme (e.g. [Hacker BW](https://dipdatta.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/pyscripter-dark-theme)) you may also need a highlighter config file as the default syntax style may not work very well with your new theme.

More info: [Pyscripter wiki:Themes and color schemes](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/Customization)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the windows logo, write %appdata%, then open "Roaming"